# PHP - Getting the next occurrence of a date between a period

Tags: php, datetime, date-range, repeat, rrule

I'm working with icalendar events that make use of **RRULE** to deal with **repetitions**;

Now, i'm aware that the are some php class like **When** and **RRules** etc.. to handle RRULE and i'm already using it, to accomplish the task of generating repeating events, but the problem is about performance with long date-range.

So i thought to speed up the task of generating repetitions by limiting the range ( start & end ) by current calendar views that are `[ MONTH, WEEK, DAY ]`.

Assuming we have a repeating event like

```
FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;DTSTART:2009-01-01
```

what i do is obviously to change the `DTSTART` to today date and to add an `UNTIL` date to limit the loop to a close range, and it is working just fine. the problem comes with rules like these:

```
FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SU;DTSTART:2009-01-01
```

or

```
FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=5;DTSTART:2009-01-01
```

with this kind of rules my trick doesn't work because the original start date doesn't match my harcoded today date.

i have tried without luck to make some iteration using DateTime Period and Interval but i can't figure it out.

So what i'm asking is a way to find when a given date will recur in my view range that can be MONTH, WEEK, or single DAY.

thanks in advance hope someone can help me. ;)

Comment: whats your hardcoded today date format ?

Comment: @Ivan Barayev: it is TZ Europe/Rome and the format is (Y-m-d H:i:s) but can be anything.. i guess

Comment: if you wanna check  this links http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/rrule.html and  https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is quite old already, but I'm going to answer just in case.

There is no *reliable* way to alter the rule like you are trying to do. As you noticed, as soon as you start having anything more than just the basic daily/weekly/monthly/yearly repetition your trick doesn't work anymore. And you haven't even scratched the surface yet, things like `BYSETPOS` and `COUNT` are a real nightmare.

You only have two approaches:

1. Either loop through all occurrences, starting from `DTSTART` ignoring anything that is before the start of your period, and stopping once you reach the end of the period
2. Or generate the full list of dates of your period, and test each one against the `RRULE`. This can be done with a process of elimination (example: your `RRULE` only occurs on Sunday and the date is not a Sunday? Then discard and move on). However in the most complex cases, the only solution is to revert to option 1 and compute all the occurrences.

While you can code these yourself, I suggest to use a lib for that. I'm the author of [php-rrule](https://github.com/rlanvin/php-rrule) and with the lib you can use `getOccurrencesBetween($begin, $end)` (that implements option 1) and `occursAt($date)` (that implements option 2).